# Add new class to css if post_meta_value matches

Tags: php, css, wordpress, class

I am trying to add a new class to posts so that I can style that class differently via css. The current class of the div is `box-layout` for all post types `event_listing`. I want that if any post's meta_key `_featured` has a meta_value of `1` then it should add a new class before or after the current class. It should be like `box-layout featured-class`.

Below is the code I am trying to use it in my theme functions.php file but haven't been successful yet.

```
add_filter('body_class','add_featured_class');
function add_featured_class ( $classes ) {
    global $post;
    if ( "1" == get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_featured', true )  ) {
        $classes[] = 'featured-class';  
    }
    // return the $classes array
    return $classes;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cant use get_the_ID() outside the loop. Try $post->ID instead.  This works for me assuming your post have the "_featured" post meta set to 1.

```
add_filter('body_class','add_featured_class');
function add_featured_class ( $classes ) {
    global $post;
    if ( "1" == get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_featured', true )  ) {
        $classes[] = 'featured-class';  
    }
    // return the $classes array
    return $classes;
}
```

Also make sure your body tag looks like this:

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

Comment: Can you tell me where this body tag can normally be located? I mean in which file? As I am not that much good at coding. Thanks

Comment: @AtharK in your theme usually in header.php

Comment: still nothing happens. I have also checked the body tag is the same as 'body_class'.

Comment: @AtharK I have tested the code and it works just fine assuming your post have the "_featured" post meta set to 1. How do you set this? Do you have this part covered? I don't think this is a built in wordpress feature.

Comment: Yes I have the post meta "_featured" set to 1. I already have another function which is working fine with the same post meta value. Only classes are not being added.

Comment: @AtharK Have you tried to verify this by dumping it's value on your screen like: var_dump(get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_featured', true )) inside you add_featured_class function after global $post; or you can even check the whole statement with var_dump(( "1" == get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_featured', true ) ));